# Odoo.sh Production URL

Tags: odoo, odoo.sh, odoo-17

I was in a trial version of Odoo Online. I then created a subscription for Odoo.sh. I installed it on Github. I have a staging and production environment. I can access the Staging instance using the Connect button.

But, how do I connect to the production instance url? Is it the original url I was using for the Online version? If I press Connect on the production branch, it just takes me back to the branch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. I needed to add /web to the end.